# Add result to existing observable which was already subscribed

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an observable of jobs array which inflates in `onInit` method:

```
jobs$: Observable<Job[]>;
  searchJob(text) {
    this.jobs$ = this.jobService.searchJobs(text, this.page).pipe(
      tap(() => this.page =+ 1),
      tap(() => this.searchJobValue = text),
      tap((res: HttpResponse<Job[]>) => this.countJobs = getPaginationTotalElements(res)),
      map((res: HttpResponse<Job[]>) => res.body),
    );
  }
```

Then when someone wants to load more jobs, I make a second requests which stays in variable a:

```
loadMore() {
    const a = this.jobService.searchJobs(this.searchJobValue, this.page).pipe(
      tap(() => this.page =+ 1),
      map((res: HttpResponse<Job[]>) => res.body),
    );
  }
```

How can I add the result of `a` to the `this.jobs$` so that I will be able to subscribe to that source in that way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(jobs$ | async) as jobs">
```

I tried many things, including `forkJoin, combineLatest, flatMap` but in most cases I ended up with ie. arrays of arrays. Does anyone has any nice tip to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should start thinking more reactively, which is hard. First you need to identify your source observables which I think are your query and the current page.

```
query$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(''); // empty string is initial value?
page$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0); // 0 is initial value?
```

I assume the data should be fetched on initializing the Component, but also when the user types and when the load more button is clicked. So in the ngOnInit you should wire up your source observables to compose your result jobs stream. Then only subscribe once. Subscribing should only be done once and after you've coded/described the behavior of your application and how it should react to changes.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.jobs$ = combineLatest(this.page$, this.query$).pipe(
    switchMap(([page, query]) => this.jobService.searchJobs(query, page))
  );
  this.subscription = this.jobs$.subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  // remember to clean up your subscription
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Now you just need to wire up the user events to your query$ and page$ observables. You could also do it in the HTML template depending on your preference.

```
onSearch(text: string): void {
  this.query$.next(text);
}

onLoadMoreClicked(): void {
  this.page$.next(this.page$.value + 1);
}
```

Some sidenotes: Try to avoid handling side effects with the tap operator. The tap operator is mainly meant for debugging/logging purposes. I also wouldn't expose the response (statuscode, etc.) to the Component from the jobservice, but just the data.

[PS. I think this is the best website to start learning RxJS ;).](https://www.learnrxjs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Since `a$` is an Observable, you can simply use `forkJoin` to combine both Observables like below.

```js
loadMore() {
    this.page += 1;

    const a$ = this.jobService.searchJobs(this.searchJobValue, this.page).pipe(
        map((res: HttpResponse<Job[]>) => res.body),
    );

    this.jobs$ = forkJoin(this.jobs$, a$).pipe(
        map(([jobs, a]) => [...jobs, ...a])
    );
}
```

Also, as already mentioned by @Joep in his answer, `tap` is usually used for logging so it's best you move that logic elsewhere. Moving it outside Observable altogether should work. It should also be `this.page += 1` and not `this.page =+ 1`. The latter just assigns `1` to `this.page` while the former is equivalent to `this.page = this.page + 1`.